# How to add multiple exports in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I following as `vue.config.js`.

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

How can I add `devServer` to `module.exports`?

```
module.exports = {
   devServer: {
   proxy: 'http://localhost:8080/',
   }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear if it's the lack of understanding of js syntax that is the problem, or there's something else. It's supposed to be `module.exports = defineConfig({ transpileDependencies: true, devServer: ... })`

Comment: @EstusFlask Apologies, new to JS. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it was that simple